# Namedpipe receiving twice in C# Server

Tags: javascript, c#, named-pipes

Iam creating a NamedPipeServer in C# and connecting it with Javascript. When iam trying to write a string in the pipe, it is receiving in the server twice.

Below given the code snipet for both server(C#) and client(JS).

Server:

```
while (receiverPipe.Read(ByBuff, 0, ByBuff.Length) != 0)
                                {
                                    Array.Resize(ref ByBuff, ByBuff.Length);

                                    int i = ByBuff.Length - 1;
                                    while (ByBuff[i] == 0 || ByBuff[i] == 254)
                                        --i;

                                    byte[] final = new byte[i + 1];
                                    Array.Copy(ByBuff, final, i + 1);

                                    rtbOutputReceive.Text += "\nMessage received as : " + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(final).ToString().Trim();
                                }
```

Client:

```
 function sendvalue(value)
    {   
      file.WriteLine(value);
    }

    function check(form)
    {
      var PipeName=form.pipeId.value ;
      // Create ActiveX Object
      object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
      // Establish a Named Pipe Connection  
      ConnectPipe(PipeName);    
    }

    function ConnectPipe(pipeName)
    {   
      file = object.CreateTextFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\"+pipeName,true);  
    }
```

**PS: But it is working fine while writing from C# Client**

Comment: Maybe a dumb question; but have you considered using web sockets instead ?

Comment: yeah, thats possible @OndrejSvejdar , but I think namedpipe is best solution for IPC.